# Binding a click event with .live() doesn't work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I'm stuck with JQuery `.live()` method that doesn't work in IE (all version). It works like a charm in FF,Chrome and Safari. Here is my code:

```
$('.down a,.up a,.navmenu').live('click', function(e){ 
    $('body').stop()
    .animate({'scrollTop': $($(this).attr('target')).position().top}, 1500); 
});
```

I'm using the latest version of Jquery. Here is the [link](http://www.posamarmizanon.it) for the website. I read others post but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Are you sure it’s the 'live' method that doesn’t work? Looks more like the animation of the body that fails. You can easily confirm this by placing an alert or console in the handler.

Comment: live() is deprecated. replace it with on()

Comment: @david you're right is not the .live() method. I placed a log in the handler. It's the body animation.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine found out the problem: it was the **$('body').stop().animate({**
IE seems to require this piece of code to work:

```
$('body, html').stop().animate({ //function
```

Now it works!